# Allowing a user to upload an MP3 to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I’m working on a website where users can upload podcasts. Podcasts are to be MP3 files, and stored in an Amazon S3 bucket.

What is the normal flow for this? I’ve Googled, but any articles relating to file uploads tend to be using the Amazon client libraries, and ideally I don’t want to use PHP (I’m using the LAMP stack) for uploading an MP3 file due to timeouts, file size limits etc.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It's a little bit confusing to avoid PHP on the Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP stack.  Is it a bucket for the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of Googling, and back-and-forth on both the GitHub repository and Amazon documentation for the new PHP SDK, I’ve got a solution using Amazon’s new PHP SDK to generate the form fields, and Uploadify to actually upload the file directly to Amazon, bypassing my server. The code looks a little like this:

```
<?php
$bucket = (string) $container['config']->images->amazon->bucket;
$options = array(
    'acl' => CannedAcl::PUBLIC_READ,
    'Content-Type' => 'audio/mpeg',
    'key' => 'audio/a-test-podcast.mp3',
    'success_action_redirect' => (string) $container['config']->main->base_url . 'upload/success/',
    'success_action_status' => 201,
    'filename' => '^'
);
$postObject = new PostObject($container['amazon_s3'], $bucket, $options);
$postObject->prepareData();

$formAttributes = $postObject->getFormAttributes();
$formInputs = $postObject->getFormInputs();

$uploadPath = $formAttributes['action'];
?>
<script>
    (function($) {
        $('#podcast').uploadify({
            'buttonClass': 'button',
            'buttonText': 'Upload',
            'formData': <?php echo json_encode($formInputs); ?>,
            'fileObjName': 'file',
            'fileTypeExts': '*.mp3',
            'height': 36,
            'multi': false,
            'onUploadError': function(file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString) {
                console.log('onUploadError', file, errorCode, errorMsg, errorString);
            },
            'onUploadSuccess': function(file, data, response) {
                console.log('onUploadSuccess', file, data, response);
            },
            'swf': '/assets/cms/swf/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': '<?php echo $uploadPath; ?>',
            'width': 120
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Amazon S3 supports [direct uploads](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/1539/direct-browser-uploading-amazon-s3-cors-fileapi-xhr2-and-signed-puts/). This might be an option here. For PHP implementation, [check out this post](http://blog.ianbeyer.com/2012/01/19/php-direct-upload-s3/).

Comment: I need something that supports IE, and *doesn’t* use PHP as per my question, as they would be greater than 2MB and exhaust PHP’s memory and/or file upload limits.

Comment: You can change the filesize limits in PHP. I belive the default is 2-6MB, but you can change it to 500MB if you want. Your webserver also has file upload limits, however, **none of this maters** since you're not uploading to your PHP server - you're uploading *directly* to S3 *using* a form generated by PHP. kxb's answer is what you need.

Comment: That is precisely the intent behind S3's direct uploads. Even though server side code is PHP, the browser directly uploads the file to S3. The upload does not go through your server (and doesn't touch PHP)

Comment: Are there any examples that use Amazon’s new PHP SDK 2? I’ve been searching for days and there doesn’t seem to be any definitive answers, just lots of questions like mine.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about the file size though you use php you can configure the upload file size limits and execution memory limit in `php.ini` file and php libraries for s3 will reduce your work. You can start from [this guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/awssdkdocsphp2/latest/gettingstartedguide/welcome.html).

Answer (score 0):

Requests to S3 must be signed with a valid secret key and always include authorization. You can do this at client side with JavaScript by theory but this would involve Ajax calls to sign your headers if you don't want to expose your secret key to the client side. Another problem will be browser compatibility. You'll have to use file slicing and calculate checksums on bigger files which is available in all modern browsers.

The simpler method would be the server-side solution with PHP or any other server-side scripting language